# why do I get an index out of bounds exception

Tags: java, for-loop

I am using a simple logic to reverse a string using a for loop, but I get an index out of bounds exception which is not making any sense to me right now

```
public class ReverseName {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String name = "Arnold Schwarzenegger";

    for(int i = name.length(); i >=0; i--) {
        System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Really? Did you try debuging `i` values?

Comment: I doubt someone who is such a beginner would know how to effectively debug a program.

Comment: `System.out.print(i);` right before `System.out.print(name.charAt(i));` If you know about `System.out.print()` then you can make it quick and easy.

Answer (score 8):

In Java indexes run from `0` to `length() - 1`, so starting the index `i` at `length()` is one off the end of the string, causing your `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Try

```
for(int i = name.length() - 1; i >=0; i--) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the character indexes of the strings starts at 0, so the index of the last character will be `name.length()-1`, and not `name.length()`

Answer (score 1):

You should start by `name.length() - 1` not by `name.length()`.

Answer (score 1):

Common index out of bounds exception cases:-

case1

```
 char[] matrix = new char[5];
 char[5] = ‘\n’;
```

case2

```
for(int i = 0; i <= array.length; ++i) {
```

case3

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
```

Java is a safe programming language and won’t let you access an invalid index of an array.
Before returning the required object perform the following check.

```
rangeCheck(index);


 private void  rangeCheck(int index) {
 if (index >= size)
      throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));
```

}

How to handle the exception?

Enclosing the code inside a try-catch statement and avoid the exception accordingly.